# My event doesn't emit from my parent component

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component that triggers a method up being click that in terms should emit an event.

```
<template>
    <div @click.self="toggleState" id="nav-icon3" :class="state">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            open : Boolean,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        toggleState: function(element){
            this.open = element.target.classList.toggle('open');
            console.log('toggle parent');
            this.$emit('onToggle', this.open);
        },
        state: function(){
            return this.open == true ? 'open' : 'false';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I try to catch this event here. Don't worry it's in a template and all I just cropped some of the code at the top. But my console.log('toggle nav'); never gets called. Why is this?

```
        <div class="grid-item-3">
            <!-- <LanguageSelect :default="defaultLanguage" /> -->
            <ButtonItem :link="'mailto:caghan.bardakci@blockburn.io'" class="button" :theme="buttonTheme">{{buttonText}}</ButtonItem>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-4">
            <HamburgerCross @onToggle="toggleHamburgerMenu" />
            <HamburgerMenu :links="links" ref="hamburgerMenu" />
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import ButtonItem from '@/components/widgets/clickables/button_item.vue'
import LanguageSelect from '@/components/widgets/language_select.vue'
import HamburgerCross from '@/components/widgets/navigation/hamburger_menu_cross.vue'
import HamburgerMenu from '@/components/widgets/navigation/hamburger_menu.vue'
export default {
    components:{
        ButtonItem,
        LanguageSelect,
        HamburgerCross,
        HamburgerMenu,
    },
    data(){
        return{
            title: 'BLOCKBURN',
            links: {'About' : '/about', 'Dapp' : '/dapp', 'Game' : '/game', 'Roadmap' : '/roadmap'},
            defaultLanguage: 'uk',
            buttonText: 'BUY BURN IEO',
            buttonTheme: 'secondary',
        }
    },
    methods:{
        toggleHamburgerMenu(event, value){
            console.log('toggle nav');
            //this.$refs.hamburgerMenu.toggle();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have some unnecessary DOM manipulation in your toggling logic. The nice thing about the virtual DOM of Vue.js is that you don't need to manipulate the DOM directly, because your DOM is automatically updated when you update your component state (= your variables). So in your caes, if you have your class based on the variable "open", you can simply manipulate the variable and the class will be updated automatically. 
In your `toggleState` function, you can simply do `this.open = !this.open`, instead of toggling the classList.

Comment: Are you seeing the logging for `toggle parent`? Is the first section of code you've included for `hamburger_menu_cross.vue`? Unrelated but... The line `open: Boolean` is using prop syntax but that isn't appropriate for a `data` property, you should just set the initial value, e.g. `open: false`. Also, inside your `state` function the variable `open` is not defined. I assume you meant `this.open`.